# Recomendation for a beginner-friendly JavaScript carousel for my first WebApp

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I am in the process of writing my first WebApp (my first use of Javascript and CSS!)- a photographic 'calculator'. You can see where I am currently at: http://domjan.fizika.org/flash.html

I have tried to present all the relevant photographic parameters as rings that you turn by swiping (clicking also works on the desktop). Turning a 'red set' of parameters also turns the top 'ambient exposure' ring in the same direction. Turning the 'blue set' ring, also turns to bottom 'flash exposure' ring.

Do you have any idea how to make this 'in-synic' turning of rings more visually obvious?

Maybe using something like an animated carousel? It should be very beginner-friendly as I have been using JavaScript for 5 days :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

these are precooked (readymade) carousel:

### Bootstrap

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

*or*

### Slide js

http://www.slidesjs.com/

*or*

if you want to cook (make) your own then use jquery animation

### jQuery animation

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp

if you are new to jQuery then :

### jQuery

http://jquery.com/

for getting start:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

Comment: Thank you for the links. I'll look into it some more but it still seems quite complicated to me (have almost no experience with JS). The thing I need that differs from all simple carousel examples I have seen is the ability to turn two different carousels in-sync by controlling only one. I would also very much like to show three values at the time (prev, next) just like I do now, and not only one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want ready-made carousels, you can look at either of these sites for ready-made widgets:

**JQuery UI**
http://jqueryui.com/

**JQuery Tools**
http://jquerytools.org/